# Approximation of $ \frac{1 - a x^2} {1 - b x^2} $ for small $x$

Tags: functions, polynomials, taylor-expansion, approximation

I am working with the following function: $$\frac{1 - a x^2} {1 - b x^2} $$ I am studying it for small values of $x$, which are between $0$ and $0.25$ and $b$ sligtly smaller (or slightly larger) than $a$.

Plotting this function, I see clearly that it can be approximated by a quadratic form that is dependent on $a - b$.

Is there a known approximation for such a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, indeed by [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

$$(1-bx^2)^{-1}=1+bx^2+O(x^4) \implies \frac{1 - a x^2} {1 - b x^2}=1+(b-a)x^2+O(x^4)$$

or by more terms

$$(1-bx^2)^{-1}=1+bx^2+bx^4+O(x^6)\implies\frac{1 - a x^2} {1 - b x^2}=1+(b-a)x^2+bx^4+O(x^6)$$

---

Note that the same result can be obtained by [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) since for $|bx^2|<1$

$$1+bx^2+b^2x^4+\ldots =\sum_{k=0}^\infty (bx^2)^k =\frac{1}{1-bx^2}$$